# Map (char -> int) over String

Tags: ocaml

I'm using Janestreet's Core and I want to basically do `String.map str (Char.to_int)`, but String.map requires the function be (char -> char) and returns a string (not a list as needed). The alternative I know of is to use a for loop and make a list, but that's not very FPish. Is there a map that take a string and a (char -> 'a) and returns an 'a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a function named `to_list_rev` in Core's extension of the String module. It translates a string into a reversed list of chars. So, you could do something like this:

```
List.rev_map Char.to_int (String.to_list_rev s)
```

**Update**

It appears that in Core, String is also a Container. The link to Container isn't working in the documentation, but I think this means that there is a `to_list` function, which feels more natural to use.

So even if you don't want to go this route, this code seems tidier than the above:

```
List.map Char.to_int (String.to_list s)
```

Comment: Eh... I'm still hoping for a better answer.

Comment: I don't blame you :-) Fwiw, it would not be so hard to just write the map function you want.

Comment: I ended up taking your advice.

Answer (score 1):

All map functions return the same container, but with different elements. The easiest solution would be:

```
  String.to_list str |> List.map ~f:Char.to_int
```

This is pretty ok, and very common idiom. Of course, you can use `rev_map` to speed things a little:

```
 String.to_list_rev str |> List.rev_map ~f:Char.to_int
```

Yet another, more cumbersome option would be to build a new list while unfolding the string using `List.init` function:

```
 let to_codes str = 
   List.init (String.length str) ~f:(fun n ->
     Char.to_int str.[n])
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote my own like Jeff suggested. Should be reasonably efficient.

```
let rec str_map_helper str f acc ind = 
    if ind = -1
      then acc
      else str_map_helper str f ((f str.[ind])::acc) (ind - 1);;

let string_map str f =
  str_map_helper str f [] ((String.length str) - 1);;
```

This should probably be done as a nested function, though.

Comment: @Romildo: Thanks for pointing that out. The solution would be to have str_map_helper return acc immediately if ind = -1, I'd edit the code but my current computer doesn't have OCaml.